# UWP: Navigation failed Unexpected status code

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, modal-dialog

In my UWP app, I have a modal in which I am able to open images, but when I try to load a local HTML file, I get this error:

> Navigation failed Unexpected status code

The error is listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.weberrorstatus as well.

How should I go about debugging this?

Comment: It's hard to tell what caused this via this simple error information, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: If you are trying to load a file from your local disk, you probably don't have access to it. What is the path to the file?

Comment: I'm able to open an image located there.

Comment: Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test? And what's the path of your html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:** The issue was that I added a new HTML file directly using file explorer.

**Solution:** Add any new file to a UWP project from inside Visual Studio so that it can be picked up during build and added to the .csproj file.